# Do you recognise this font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Does anyone recognise this font please?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running this against what the font?

Comment: I don't think that's a true inline typeface. Looks like it was converted to paths and given thick strokes (and not for the better).

Comment: "What the font" gave very poor results, didn't even recognise the angles on the 'C'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font appears to be a modified version of [GOVERNOR](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=governor) and I am basing that on the R and C:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a little irony in a typeface inspired by Miami Beach being used for San Francisco. :)

Comment: Thats the one, it seams to fit the other letters no problem.